# how to solve XQ=0 type matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I have 2 matrices, Q and X such that XQ=0. X is 1x16 matrix with unknown values i.e. X=[x1, x2, x3, x4, ...x16]. Q is 16x16 real valued matrix. How can I find values of X in Matlab? code please...

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html Matrix division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `null` function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html

It provides the solution to the problem

```
 A*x=0
```

The solutions to

```
Q'*X' = 0
```

are the same as

```
X*Q = 0
```

So

```
X = null(Q')'
```

Answer (score 0):

If det(Q)~=0, then unique solution is x=zeros(1,16).
If det(Q)==0, the set of solutions form a vector space of dimension r=16-rank(Q). In fact, the solutions are the kernel of Q, so you can use the function `eig` to find the corresponding eigenvectors, which form a basis of your solutions.